# Pytesseract image reading bugs out at the last half of text, every time

Tags: python, python-tesseract, text-recognition

So im working on a nitro type bot and the simplest way that I could think of was a bot powered by text recognition. The bot takes the screen shots perfectly everytime, but more than half of the itme it has trouble reading the latter half of the text.

[image: The screenshot that it takes]

*screenshot above*

The results that i get:

*ignore the B at the start, i know the problem there*

```
B new type of fiber optic cable may do just that. Fiber optic cables contain bundles of thin, flexible glass fibers Fa ivein Cane Tetea TFSI ITTF Ce TN | LAN OF CAT TELOTING Maca Tate RINS
```

here is the code I used:

```
import time
import keyboard
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from PIL import Image,ImageGrab
import cv2
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

# Takes screenshot of text

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(412,563,1054, 701)).save('text.png')

# Turn image into text
text = image_to_string('text.png')

# cleans the text
text = text.replace('\n',' ')
print(text)

# main bot starts typing it

time.sleep(1)
keyboard.write(text)
```

Comment: ive tried grayscale btw, same results

Comment: Also when i make it actually type out the random letters in the latter half, it actually just continues with the text in the screenshot like normal. Its wierd

Comment: You have a slight (background) gradient in your image. Threshold your image, e.g. using Otsu's method, and you should be fine - at least, works for me.